# EclipseLink: generate List with initialization

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I use EclipseLink in Spring to generate all my model classes from my database. And I let EclipseLink to create List of objects instead of set for table (object) mappings. The problem is that EL only declare the List without Initialize it, so I have to check for Null everytime I try to access the List. Is there a way I can tell EclipseLink to initialize the List too when creating models? Here is the example of what I have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="ad")
private List<MapUserAd> mapUserAds;
```

I want:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="ad")
private List<MapUserAd> mapUserAds = new ArrayList<MapUserAd>();
```

Comment: Just a little hint that may be helpful to you or not: EclipseLink (or maybe that's even standard JPA behaviour?) always initializes relationship collections when populating entities from JPQL queries. So at least in that case a null check is not required.

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about entity generation, something done by Eclipse, not EclipseLink.  Are you using the dali subproject? https://wiki.eclipse.org/Dali